# comparing 2 files in csv based on few columns and replace one column in first file with the value of matched from another col in 2nd file using shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, csv

i have a bit of an ask in comparing 2 files based on respective columns which are not in order.

file 1

```
AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH (header)
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh
```

file2

```
GGGG,AAAA,CCCC,DDDD,HHHH,EEEE,BBBB,FFFF,IIII (header)
g,a,c,d,h,e,b,f,i
gg,aa,cc,dd,hh,ee,bb,ff,ii
```

in the above example i have to compare 4 different columns  from file 1 with 4 columns in file 2 , if a match is found update the file 2 with a added column saying matched and do not use the row again for comparision and replace a column on file 1 with a column in file 2

compare file 1 and file 2 for the 6 columns from a to h and then if match found replace the column a with column i

the final file should be
file 3

```
AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH
i,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
ii,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh
```

Comment: The question is hard to understand and read as it is. Please use the appropriate code formatting to present the contents of your example files. Crucially, use actual line breaks to represent different lines, instead of separating them with spaces. I also understand that english might not be your primary language, but please consider revising your requests and use appropriate punctuation. If you expect people to put an effort in answering your questions, you should also put an effort when asking them.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to add proper formatting for the input and output examples. Also, be sure to include what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Comment: It is unclear what four columns should be used for the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to perform a relational JOIN operation on the named fields that the two files have in common:

```bash
$ mlr --csv join -j AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH -f file1.csv file2.csv
AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH,IIII
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh,ii
```

To then replace the contents of the `AAAA` column with that of `IIII` we may move the `IIII` column to the start while at the same time removing the `AAAA` column (this is done with Miller's `cut` operation), followed by relabelling `IIII` as `AAAA` (which is done with Miller's `label` operation):

```bash
mlr --csv \
    join -j AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH -f file1.csv then \
    cut -o -f IIII,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH then \
    label AAAA file2.csv
```

The `cut` operation could be split into two separate steps; one that excludes the `AAAA` field and one that reorders the remaining fields so that `IIII` is first.  This would allow us to avoid the long list of fields:

```bash
mlr --csv \
    join -j AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH -f file1.csv then \
    cut -x -f AAAA then \
    reorder -f IIII then \
    label AAAA file2.csv
```

The final output:

```
AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,GGGG,HHHH
i,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
ii,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh
```